# Take arbitrary git working copy and make exactly the same as remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-clone, git-remote

Say I have an arbitrary local git working directory that was cloned from some remote. I want to make the local git repository be EXACTLY the same as the remote, irrespective of what's happened to the local directory since it was cloned. I do not want to do another full clone.

Say the local working directory has:

- additional untracked files
- deleted files
- staged changes.
- may be on some arbitrary branch.
- have a bunch of commits since being cloned from remote

Now I want to make this local repository reflect remote exactly. Here's my current solution but I'm not sure if it covers all cases and whether there is an easier solution:

```
git stash
git clean -f -x -d
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull origin master
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The final `git pull` is definitely redundant after the `fetch` + `reset`.

Comment: Your local repository has a working copy whereas your remote is a bare  repository. Inherently they are different in this fundamental way and there is no way to make the "EXACTLY" the same. You can duplicate the objects and references exactly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git reset --hard
```

will dump any changes that you have including any you have staged.

```
git clean -xdf
```

will get rid of anything in your working directory that git is not tracking due to ignore or exclude.

```
git checkout HEAD
```

will put you on no branch so you can clean everything out.

```
git branch | xargs git branch -D
```

will delete all your local branches

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
```

will delete all your tags

```
git prune origin
```

will get rid of any tracking branches that are no longer on the remote

```
git fetch
```

will get any branches and tags from the remote that you don't have. You can stop here and checkout any remote branches you want to work on while creating a local branch with

```
git checkout origin/master
```

or you can create local branches that point to where all existing remote branches are pointing to as of your fetch with

```
git branch -r | xargs -n 1 git checkout
```

Comment: So if you were to do a git push origin master after all of this, there would be 0 changes in all cases?

Comment: yes. If you do each one of those things, you would not have anything to push.

Comment: one thing to consider is that if you are working on Windows, your line endings may be registering as changes. Adding them and committing will give you something that will end up getting pushed.

Answer (score 3):

The following set of commands should get you into an identical state with the remote branch:

```
git checkout -f master                # Check out the local 'master' branch
git fetch origin                      # Fetch the 'origin' remote
git reset --hard origin/master        # Reset all tracked files to remote state
git clean -dxff                       # Remove all non-tracked files
```

Note that (for obvious reasons), these commands are potentially destructive - that is, any local changes that are overwritten by this and not saved in a commit accessible by some other means will be lost.